# What are the common practices in the front-end development for a Ruby-on-Rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend

In a Rails web application project, I have been assigned to develop the front end which will be rich of dynamic forms (users will be able to add elements/components into the form) and charts for enterprise customers. I have limited front end experience so I would like to hear the up-to-date practices of very experienced front end developers like "use this JS framework and stay away from that one" "take a look at this book" "check out those links" "X tool is great" "consider this workflow" etc.

Comment: Don't know why someone voted down your question... Maybe Stackoverflow is not the best place to ask such a thing? Well, whatever, for the JS framework you should use the default Rails 3 one which is JQuery (I'm sure you already heard about it). For the book you should look at "Learn Rails By Example" by Michael Hartl.

Comment: Agreed, Kulgar. I think it's a valid and useful question for SO. Voted it up.

Comment: Vote down again because even if it's a valuable question it really doesn't belong unfortunately

Comment: Asking a single question of "which path is the right" before choosing the path is supposed to be wiser than asking hundreds of "how to proceed on this way" questions after the wrong choice. I just wanted to know the right path(s) for a rails app. which will consist of many dynamic forms and charts. It is also ironic that the question has been closed by someone who answered the "the best C++ IDE for Windows" question as "Visual Studio is the best IDE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the question is inappropriate.. bumped it back to 0

Rails renders views using various template languages. [erb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) is the default and should be fine to start with. Check out the [guide on rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more information.

Rails 3.1(?) includes [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) by default, so it's available in default apps. Good to be familiar with.

I'd also check out the [guide on form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no definitive answer to this therefore doesn't belong on SO

Comment: ah good point.. more of a discussion question